# Setting up server-side PHP includes with XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, ssi

I've perused some [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html) and other SO questions regarding setting up SSI on Apache, but I can't find the answer to my problem.

I just received files for a project that utilizes PHP SSI rather than the SHTML extension. I thought I could change the lines in httpd.conf from .shtml to .php:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

But this does not work.

For thoroughness' sake, here is an example of the include code (from index.html):

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/aboutbar.php" -->
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: SSI and PHP are two different things. If you want to include a file in PHP you need configure Apache to use PHP (typically mod_php) and then use a PHP include.  `<?php include('/includes/aboutbar.php'); ?>`

Comment: Yes, I've used PHP includes before, but is there a way to enable the behavior that I've outlined in my question? These are project files sent to me from someone else, and since this is the setup they're using on the live server apparently, I'd like to recreate that on my own environment.

Comment: It's been so long since I've used SSI. But after thinking about it, you shouldn't have to change anything. SSI should include the PHP script as it would include any other file. Used to do that with CGI scripts.